# Unable to create or query tables in online sql interpreter

Tags: sql

I've been trying to simply create and display information from these tables on an interpreter that uses sql.js to run.

I've looked through assignment forums and tried to assign primary keys in varying formats based on what was provided on w3schools and also tried to explicitly create a database to put the tables into. no changes.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees;
CREATE TABLE pledges( donorId       integer ,  donor    text,
                          pledge integer,     AmountPaid integer,
                    );

 INSERT INTO pledges VALUES (1,'JOHNSON',6,30);
 INSERT INTO pledges VALUES (2,'ROGERS',5,100);
 INSERT INTO pledges VALUES (1,'RODDUCK',10,50);
 INSERT INTO pledges VALUES (1,'PETERS',2,20);
 INSERT INTO pledges VALUES (1,'ALBERTSON',7,56);

 SELECT * FROM pledges;
```

The expectation is just for me to create the simple tables and test the queries but it just keeps saying "fetching results"

Comment: Why are you dropping a table named `employees` but creating one named `pledges`?

Answer (score 1):

Your online tool probably swallows the error due to the incorrect CREATE TABLE statement. You have a dangling `,` after the `amountpaid integer` definition:

Once that error is fixed (and the `pledges` table is dropped instead of the `employees` table), your script runs fine:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pledges;
CREATE TABLE pledges
( 
  donorId    integer,  
  donor      text,
  pledge     integer,     
  amountpaid integer --<< you had a comma here
);

INSERT INTO pledges VALUES (1,'JOHNSON',6,30);
INSERT INTO pledges VALUES (2,'ROGERS',5,100);
INSERT INTO pledges VALUES (1,'RODDUCK',10,50);
INSERT INTO pledges VALUES (1,'PETERS',2,20);
INSERT INTO pledges VALUES (1,'ALBERTSON',7,56);

SELECT * 
FROM pledges;
```

https://rextester.com/BJJGC94351

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the exact problem I found out after about another 45 minutes of tearing my hair out lmao.